# Invalid entry size (ZipException) when reading Excel file in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I got an exception java.util.zip.ZipException when i reading my excel file.

I create a maven project and i added apache poi and poi ooxm in my dependencies.

When i read file to count the number of column , i get an error

This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         String path = "C:\\testData.xlsx";
         File excelFile = new File (path);
         FileInputStream fis = null;
         try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
         //we create an XSSF Workbook object for our XLSX Excel File
         XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
         try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
         //We get first sheet
         XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);   
         int totalColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

         System.out.println("Total number of Columns :::"+totalColumns);
   }
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.tata</groupId>
  <artifactId>trenProg</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>trenProg</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->

                <dependency>

                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

                    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>

                    <version>4.0.1</version>

                </dependency>

                <dependency>

                  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

                  <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>

                  <version>3.9</version>

                </dependency>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>junit</groupId>

      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

      <version>4.11</version>

      <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

 

  <build>

    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->

      <plugins>

        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>3.1.0</version>

        </plugin>

        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>3.0.2</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>3.8.0</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>2.22.1</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>3.0.2</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>2.5.2</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>2.8.2</version>

        </plugin>

        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>3.7.1</version>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>

          <version>3.0.0</version>

        </plugin>

      </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

  </build>

</project>
```

This is the full exception trace

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 1053 bytes)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:55)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:204)
    at com.avm.trainjava.ReaderExcel.main(ReaderExcel.java:28)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.avm.trainjava.ReaderExcel.main(ReaderExcel.java:34)
```

Have you an idea what i have this error ? I doesn't use zip class in my java code.

Comment: XLSX is a ZIP format, and if you rename the extension to ".zip" it can be opened with a ZIP file viewer.

Comment: Please post pom.xml

Comment: hi @g00se, i updated my post. you can see my pom.xml file

Comment: hi @DuncG, i doesn't understand. I must rename my xlsx file to zip file ?

Comment: Oh and can you post the *full* exception stack trace please?

Comment: Hi @g00se, i updated my post, you can see the full stack trace error which i got. Have you an idea to fix it please ?

Comment: You can open that file OK without errors in Excel? Try another simple spreadsheet file as well. Oh and how are you running that?

Comment: Hi @g00se, I opened this file in Excel app without error. I try also another file, i have the same error

Answer (score 0):

The following pom works for me with your code (your original didn't)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.tata</groupId>
  <artifactId>trenProg</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>trenProg</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <poi.version>5.0.0</poi.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <!--
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>

            <version>4.0.1</version>

    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi @g00se , effectively, your pom works. Now i want to know which dependencies jar are being added with this dependency <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Hi @g00se, i did mvn dependency:tree but this command line download many jar and gives me information. There is possible to see this dependecies jar in my eclipse ?

Comment: Don't know sorry - I don't use Eclipse